# h:panelGroup style attribute appears twice in generated HTML

Tags: jsf, attributes, duplicates

i just viewed the source Code of my project and found the following (style attribute generated twice):

```
<span style="color: #bb0000;" style="color: #bb0000;">Hello</span>
```

generated from this JSF-Code:

```
<h:panelGroup style="color: #bb0000;">
    <h:outputText value="Hello" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

but if i change this to:

```
<h:panelGroup >
    <h:outputText value="Hello" style="color: #bb0000;"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

this generates a correct html:

```
<span style="color: #bb0000;">Hello</span>
```

the above is just an example for testing!

same thing happens for display: inline-block; ....etc!

ENV: JSF Mojarra 2.2.0 on Tomcat 8

any idea / explaination why this happen?

Comment: Which specific version of Mojarra? Tried a different one  (2.2 is just a JSF api version). I cannot seem to find any comparable issues using a searchengine

Comment: @Kukeltje, Mojarra 2.2.0 as i wrote in the question, i searched online to find anything about this issue, but found nothing

Comment: In the question you wrote Mojarra 2.2, not 2.2.0...! That is by now a 2.5 year old version. Tried a newer one?Checked the releasenotes? I just did... And guess what ;-) fixed in 2.2.8. If you are a developer, always, always, always check newer versions if you encounter weird behaviour, always, always, always, check releasenotes... So much easier and way little time needed then creating a question

Comment: oh,do you have a direct link to that fix/bug?

Comment: It's on the Mojarra releasenotes site. Easy to find. I just closed the tab it was on

Comment: ok, thanks, but if you always always face a little small problem, you think always always this could be a bug and check the releasenotes?

Comment: UPDATE: its a bug in Mojarra 2.2.0 and fixed in 2.2.8

link to the Bug/Fix: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3270

Comment: getting duplicate styles is not a little problem, it is a weird problem. Especially if you just have it once in your code. And yes, I very, very often check the releasnotes then, but better yet, I try to keep on 'latest versions' first. Please create an answer yourself

Comment: @Kukeltje, honestly i did. but not directly on JSF Website, but via Eclipse JavaEE IDE. and it shows me that only Mojarra 2.2.0 for download available. so i thought its the last!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a bug in Mojarra 2.2.0 and fixed in 2.2.8

and here is the link to the Bug/Fix: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3270